# No Module named ldtputils in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run following code with a basic function to open a webpage, that is mainly the front page for a router, enter username and passsword and press enter. I am getting error "No Module named ldtputils" everytime I run using Python3. Please help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
import time
from ldtp import *
from ldtputils import *    
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/geckodriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get('http://192.168.10.1')
time.sleep(4)
generatekeyevent('user')
keypress('<tab>')
generatekeyevent('pass')
keypress('<tab>')
keypress('<enter>')
```

Comment: Unless you need anything from the `ldtputils` module, you can just remove the `from ldtputils import *` line.

Comment: I think the generatekeyevent function is coming from ldtputils. if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download it for that python version. You can use `pip3` for
installing `ldtputils` package for python3 version.

Use this command:

`sudo -H pip3 install ldtputils`

Also if you haven't used pip3 before and not installed it; then you need to install it first. Use this command:

`sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip`

Comment: No matching distribution found for ldtputils.

Comment: then try to install it via apt-get